# What does ".=" mean in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've seen these characters used together in Wordpress PHP, but I'm not sure what they do. An example:

> $content .= '' . $title . '';

Comment: In the future, this is a great resource, especially because you can't search for symbols in google: [Symbol Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

That is the short hand version of a concatenation where you say append something to the end of this string itself. It means

```
$content = $content. $title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats a php string concatenation operation. For example

```
$str1 = "Hello";
$str2 = "World";
$str1 .= " " . $str2; // is equal to writing $str1 = $str1 . " " . $str2;
echo $str1 // will print Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as this :

```
$content = $content . '' . $title . '';
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a concatenation assignment operator

```
$x="Hello";
$x .= " world!";
echo $x; // outputs Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

`$a .= $b` means `$a = $a . $b`

This also apply to some other operations such as +, -, *, /, ...
For example:

```
$a += $b    => $a = $a + $b
$a -= $b    => $a = $a - $b
$a *= $b    => $a = $a * $b
$a /= $b    => $a = $a / $b
```